# User systemd service does not restart after suspend

Tags: linux, systemd

I have created a user systemd service to restart spotifyd after suspend as it is suggested in the spotifyd git hub page. The problem I have is that it never restarts after suspend.

This is the restartSpotifyd service file. I have removed the

> Restart=always

from the restartSpotifyd.service file because I was hitting the start limit ('start-limit-hit'). This is the updated version of the service file:

.config/systemd/user/restartSpotifyd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart spotifyd after resume
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --user --no-block restart spotifyd.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

When I suspend and restart the computer and I get this:

```
systemctl --user status restartSpotifyd
● restartSpotifyd.service - Restart spotifyd after resume
     Loaded: loaded (/home/netlak/.config/systemd/user/restartSpotifyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: Stopped Restart spotifyd after resume.
May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: Started Restart spotifyd after resume.
May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: restartSpotifyd.service: Succeeded.
May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: restartSpotifyd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: Stopped Restart spotifyd after resume.
May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: restartSpotifyd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: restartSpotifyd.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
May 26 15:04:13 jamming systemd[1361]: Failed to start Restart spotifyd after resume.
May 26 15:06:21 jamming systemd[1361]: Started Restart spotifyd after resume.
May 26 15:06:21 jamming systemd[1361]: restartSpotifyd.service: Succeeded.
```

At 15:10 I suspended the computer but the service has not been restarted when waking up. Last time it was restarted was when I manually restarted the service at 15:06.

This is happening in Debian and Archlinux.
Can anyone hint me what I'm missing here?